# Haml if statement issue

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I'm having an HAML issue writing an if else statement ...

I have this code :

```
- experiences.each_index do |index|
  - if index % 2 == 0 ?
    .group
      .left
  - else
    .right
  %p= experiences[index].company
```

And I would like to produce that kind of html:

```
<div class='group'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Multiple times depending on my collection's lenght.

Any idea ? Thanks

EDIT>
A workaround would be to do this :

```
  - experiences.each_index do |index|
  - if index % 2 == 0 ?
    .group
      .left
        experiences[index]...
      .right
        experiences[index+1]...
```

But isn't there any better solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of):

```
- experiences.in_groups_of(2) do |left, right|
  .group
    .left
      %p= left.company
    .right
      %p= right.company if right
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Working with Middleman, I don't have access to in_groups_of.
However, each_slice from ruby does the same job :)